# Can NTLM pass-through authentication be done without NetLogon?

Tags: windows, domain, ntlm

In any "recent" documentation regarding NTLM ([Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-apds/5bfd942e-7da5-494d-a640-f269a0e3cc5d)) I see it stated that the mechanism of pass-through authentication is done over a NetLogon channel, which should be secure. This secure channel is also used to pass the session key from the Domain Controller to the server.

However, older information I have found, for example [CIFS Logon and Pass Through Authentication](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/pdf/draft-leach-cifs-logon-spec-00#section-3), states that there is another mechanism with which a server can use the help of a Domain Controller to authenticate a user. This mechanism is described, essentially, as a man-in-the-middle operation, where the server just relays all messages between the client and Domain Controller for the authentication process.
Is this possible? In which scenarios? If so - how is the session key safely passed from the Domain Controller to the server in this case?

Answer (score 0):

NTLM authentication has two methods: `secure NetLogon` channel and `LanManager` signing & sealing. The latter uses unencrypted relayed communications between clients, servers, and DCs, making it vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, and no safe transmission of session keys occurs in this scenario.

Comment: So is the key transferred together with the authentication confirmation message or is session security just flat out unsupported in this case?